# forecast "point" doesnt show the right month

Tags: forecasting

i have 8 months of data from jan to aug2012, i want to forecast for jul to dec2012 by feeding only jan to jun2012 data and then measuring forecast accuracy. when i check the forecast object returned, it shows the wrong year. can you please help....here's the code i have

```
> ontime.ts<-ts(ontime$ontime, frequency=12, start=c(2012,1), end = c(2012,6))
> ontime.ts
     Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun
2012 100 100  96 100 100  98
> ontime.forecast=forecast(ontime.ts,h=6)
> ontime.forecast
         Point Forecast Lo 80 Hi 80 Lo 95 Hi 95
Jul 2012             99    97   101    96   102
Aug 2013             99    97   101    96   102
Sep 2013             99    97   101    96   102
Oct 2013             99    97   101    96   102
Nov 2013             99    97   101    96   102
Dec 2013             99    97   101    96   102
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I get running *exactly* the same code using the current github version of the forecast package.

```
> ontime.forecast=forecast(ontime.ts,h=6)
> ontime.forecast
         Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80    Lo 95   Hi 95
Jul 2012       98.99996 97.04227 100.9577 96.00592 101.994
Aug 2012       98.99996 97.04227 100.9577 96.00592 101.994
Sep 2012       98.99996 97.04227 100.9577 96.00592 101.994
Oct 2012       98.99996 97.04227 100.9577 96.00592 101.994
Nov 2012       98.99996 97.04227 100.9577 96.00592 101.994
Dec 2012       98.99996 97.04227 100.9577 96.00592 101.994
```

You will need to provide a reproducible example if want any additional help.